# How to write an SQL aggregate function/query

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have a query that displays the total value (sum of amount) for each day. 
The query:

```
SELECT CAST(date AS DATE), SUM(amount) AS total_amount FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 00:00:00'
GROUP BY CAST(date AS DATE)
```

The CAST is to abbreviate the datetime format to just a date.

Now I want to select only the day which has the highest sum with the max function. 
To do this I tried writing the following aggregate query:

```
SELECT s.date, s.total_amount
FROM (SELECT CAST(date AS DATE), SUM(amount) AS total_amount FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 00:00:00'
GROUP BY CAST(date AS DATE)) s
WHERE s.total_amount = (SELECT MAX(s.total_amount) FROM table)
```

This does not work. I know the problem is with the final WHERE clause, but I need help with making it work.

Comment: please tag your SQL engine.

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: I'm not using a specific SQL engine/DBMS so I need a general (universal) SQL query.

Comment: @ire: the "universal" SQL is the either the one `row_number()` (see zealous' answer) or the CTE from Yogesh's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT` :

```
SELECT CAST(date AS DATE), SUM(amount) AS total_amount 
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 00:00:00'
GROUP BY CAST(date AS DATE)
ORDER BY total_amount DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you are working with `SQL Server` then you can use `TOP` :

```
SELECT TOP (1) CAST(date AS DATE), SUM(amount) AS total_amount 
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 00:00:00'
GROUP BY CAST(date AS DATE)
ORDER BY total_amount DESC;
```

If you want ties then you can use window function :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT CAST(date AS DATE), SUM(amount) AS total_amount,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC) as Seq
      FROM table
      WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 00:00:00'
      GROUP BY CAST(date AS DATE)
     ) t
WHERE seq = 1;
```

You can use `CTE` :

```
WITH CTE AS (
     SELECT CAST(date AS DATE), SUM(amount) AS total_amount 
     FROM table
     WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 00:00:00'
     GROUP BY CAST(date AS DATE)
)  
SELECT c.*
FROM CTE C
WHERE C.total_amount = (SELECT MAX(total_amount) FROM CTE);
```

Note : If your DBMS doesn't support `CTE` expression then you need repeat the `SELECT` statement in Subquery.

```
SELECT CAST(date AS DATE), SUM(amount) AS total_amount 
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 00:00:00'
GROUP BY CAST(date AS DATE)
HAVING SUM(amount) = (SELECT MAX(total_amount)
                      FROM (SELECT CAST(date AS DATE), SUM(amount) AS total_amount 
                            FROM table
                            WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 00:00:00'
                            GROUP BY CAST(date AS DATE)
                           ) t
                     );
```

Comment: This works but I'd like to know how to do it with an aggregate function. Do you know how I could make it work?

Comment: @ire: you can't have an aggregate without using aggregate function. That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server then you can use `TOP`

```
SELECT TOP 1 CAST(date AS DATE), SUM(amount) AS total_amount 
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 00:00:00'
GROUP BY CAST(date AS DATE)
ORDER BY total_amount DESC
```

Use window function `row_number()` - should work with MySQL 8.0, PostgreSQL, Oracle and SQL Server.

```
select
    date,
    total_amount
from
(
    SELECT 
        CAST(date AS DATE) as date, 
        SUM(amount) AS total_amount,
        row_number() over (order by SUM(amount) desc) as rnk 
    FROM table
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY CAST(date AS DATE)
) val
where rnk = 1
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using the top or rnk and use an aggregate function like I showed in my post. Do you know how I could make it work?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT s.dt, s.total_amount
FROM (SELECT CAST(date AS DATE) as dt, SUM(amount) AS total_amount 
      FROM table
      WHERE CAST(date as date) BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
      GROUP BY CAST(date AS DATE)) s
WHERE s.total_amount = (Select max(total_amount)
                        FROM (SELECT  CAST(date AS DATE) as dt, SUM(amount) AS total_amount 
                              FROM table
                              WHERE CAST(date as date) BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
                              GROUP BY CAST(date AS DATE)) ss )`

Comment: I think the above will give you what you want but I am still trying to ascertain why you can not use rank or top functions for your need.